# Golang: Validate Struct field of type string to be one of specific values

Tags: json, validation, go, struct

golang version: `1.18.3`

validator: `github.com/go-playground/validator/v10`

I want to validate an incoming JSON payload after loaded into nested struct data structure. Here's my incoming JSON payload,

```
{
  "name": "Duro",
  "gender": "MALE",
  "tier": 3,
  "mobileNumber": "0356874586",
  "address": {
    "city": "Tokyo",
    "street": "Shibaura St"
  },
  "children":[
    {
      "title": "Mr",
      "lastName": "Takayashi"
    }
  ],
  "isEmployed": false,
  "requestedAt": "2022-01-10T03:30:12.639Z"
}
```

Here's my user.go file,

```
package main

type User struct {
        Name                   string                     `validate:"required"`
        Gender                 string                     `validate:"required,oneof=MALE FEMALE"`
        Tier                   *uint8                     `validate:"required,eq=0|eq=1|eq=2|eq=3"`
        MobileNumber           string                     `validate:"required"`
        Email                  string
        Address                *Address  `validate:"required"`
        Children               []Child   `validate:"required,dive"`
        IsEmployed             *bool     `validate:"required"`
        PreferredContactMethod string    `validate:"oneof=EMAIL PHONE POST SMS"`
        RequestedAt            time.Time `validate:"required"`
    }
    type Address struct {
        City   string `validate:"required"`
        Street string `validate:"required"`
    }
    
    type Child struct {
        Title     string `validate:"required"`
        FirstName string
        LastName  string `validate:"required"`
    }
```

Here's my test function

```
func TestUserPayload(t *testing.T) {
    validate := validator.New()
    var u User

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &u)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err := validate.Struct(&u)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("error %v", err)
    }

}
```

This test fails with error,

```
error Key: 'User.PreferredContactMethod' Error:Field validation for 'PreferredContactMethod' failed on the 'oneof' tag
```

This happens because Go assigns empty string to User.PreferredContactMethod struct field. Since `PreferredContactMethod` is NOT a required field, I DON'T want to see this validation error when json payload doesn't have it.
How can I avoid this error message when the json payload doesn't have `preferredContactMethod` field?

If you have better alternatives to achieve this validation, happy to hear them as well.

Here's [the code in Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/uRwzX2bSNDE)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Utilize `omitempty` along with `oneof` to make the validator library ignore empty or unset values.

```
type User struct {
        Name                   string                     `validate:"required"`
        Gender                 string                     `validate:"required,oneof=MALE FEMALE"`
        Tier                   *uint8                     `validate:"required,eq=0|eq=1|eq=2|eq=3"`
        MobileNumber           string                     `validate:"required"`
        Email                  string
        Address                *Address  `validate:"required"`
        Children               []Child   `validate:"required,dive"`
        IsEmployed             *bool     `validate:"required"`
        PreferredContactMethod string    `validate:"omitempty,oneof=EMAIL PHONE POST SMS"`
        RequestedAt            time.Time `validate:"required"`
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using https://github.com/marrow16/valix (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/marrow16/valix) it could be achieved with the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/marrow16/valix"
)

type User struct {
    Name                   string    `json:"name" v8n:"required, notNull"`
    Gender                 string    `json:"gender" v8n:"required, notNull, &strtoken{['MALE','FEMALE']}"`
    Tier                   uint8     `json:"tier" v8n:"required, notNull, &mini{0}, &maxi{3}"`
    DateOfBirth            string    `json:"dateOfBirth" v8n:"notNull, &strisod"`
    MobileNumber           string    `json:"mobileNumber" v8n:"required, notNull, &strpatt{'^([0-9]{8,16})$'}"`
    Email                  string    `json:"email" v8n:"notNull"`
    Address                Address   `json:"address" v8n:"required, notNull"`
    Children               []Child   `json:"children" v8n:"required, notNull"`
    IsEmployed             bool      `json:"isEmployed" v8n:"required"`
    PreferredContactMethod string    `json:"preferredContactMethod" v8n:"notNull, &strtoken{['EMAIL','PHONE','POST','SMS']}"`
    RequestedAt            time.Time `json:"requestedAt" v8n:"required, notNull, &strisodt"`
}
type Address struct {
    City   string `json:"city" v8n:"required, notNull"`
    Street string `json:"street" v8n:"required, notNull"`
}

type Child struct {
    Title     string `json:"title" v8n:"required, notNull"`
    FirstName string `json:"firstName" v8n:"notNull"`
    LastName  string `json:"lastName" v8n:"required, notNull"`
}

const jsonData = `{
  "name": "Duro",
  "gender": "MALE",
  "tier": 3,
  "dateOfBirth": "2000-01-13",
  "mobileNumber": "0356874586",
  "address": {
    "city": "Tokyo",
    "street": "Shibaura St"
  },
  "children":[
    {
      "title": "Mr",
      "lastName": "Takayashi"
    }
  ],
  "isEmployed": false,
  "requestedAt": "2022-01-10T03:30:12.639Z"
}`

var UserRequestValidator = valix.MustCompileValidatorFor(User{}, nil)

func main() {
    user := User{}

    ok, violations, _ := UserRequestValidator.ValidateStringInto(jsonData, &user)

    if ok {
        fmt.Println("Validation successful")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Validation failed! (violations: %d)", len(violations)))
        for _, v := range violations {
            fmt.Printf("%s (property: '%s', path: '%s')\n", v.Message, v.Property, v.Path)
        }
    }
}
```

Go playground here: https://go.dev/play/p/3zrkZx97m-e

Disclosure: I am the author of Valix